# How to make vim pretend to have a flat source directory from a complex tree?

Tags: vim, autocomplete, workflow, development-environment

I often find myself working in projects with directory structures similar to this:

```
a/
  x/
    file1.h
  y/
    file2.h
  z/
    file3.h
b/
  u/
    file4.cpp
    file5.h
  v/
    file6.cpp
    file7.cpp
  w/
```

where source files are spread over all the directories.

I have a shortcut such that saying Ctrl+n opens a `:tabnew` prompt, but I still find it cumbersome to find the file I want myself by just typing/auto-completing the directories, as I have to remember where a particular file that I want to open lives.

Can I get vim to pretend the entire directory structure to be flat, or rather do a find and then open? I'd like to still have auto completion.
Of course, there could be name clashes in theory, but for most cases you wont have files of the same name in separate directories even if you technically could.

---

So what I want is for the source directory to appear as if it looked like this:

```
    file1.h
    file2.h
    file3.h
    file4.cpp
    file5.h
    file6.cpp
    file7.cpp
```

Allowing me to type something like `:magiccommand f<TAB>2<TAB>` to open `a/y/file2.h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:help 'path'`

In your case, something like this:

```
:set path=/path/to/a/**,/path/to/b/**
```

Then `:tabf file4.cpp`. So change your shortcut to be `:tabfind` instead of `:tabnew`.

I'd also suggest that you look into using `ctags`, because then you can jump directly to symbols in any file in your project with `:tag MyExcellentFunction` (or `:stag ..` or `:tab stag ...`).

If you do end up using tags and drop your `tags` file in the project root, this'll help you out:

```
function! SetUpPath(filepath)
    setlocal path=
    for l:tagfile in tagfiles()
        let l:tagpath = fnamemodify(l:tagfile, ":h")
        execute "setlocal path+=" . fnameescape(l:tagpath) . '/**'
    endfor
    setlocal path-=.
    setlocal path-=
    setlocal path-=
endfunction

autocmd BufEnter * call SetUpPath(fnamemodify(expand("<afile>"), ":p"))
```

(This could also be modified to look for .git or .svn directories if that's your pleasure.)

Comment: This is really interesting. How does the tags file really work? Where do I put my paths?

Comment: `:help tags` will get you going on what they're all about, `:help ctags` will point you to some tools to generate them. I use exuberant ctags and universal ctags depending on the system. It takes some fiddling to get the options just the way you want but I code mostly in C++ and from the project root directory I run `ctags -R --extra=+q --tag-relative=yes -f tags.tmp .` and then when it's done I delete the existing tags file and rename this one. In my vimrc I have the line `set tags=tags;` (the semicolon is important) to find the tags file.

Answer (score 3):

There exists several fuzzyfinders that help to accomplish that -- I even wrote one a long time ago.

You can also stick to vanilla Vim and use *starstar*: `:sp **/f*2<tab>`.

If you set `'path'` correctly, you could also type `:find +sp f<tab>` (it doesn't seem to work with `:tabedit` though).

Comment: `:sfind` is a split variant of `:find`. You can also do `:tab sfind` to make `:find` open a new tab.

Comment: That doesn't appear to work. Tabbing after the file name just removes the input after `:sp`. And find searches in `$PATH` not in `$PWD`.

Comment: `:find` doesn't search in `$PATH`, it searches in `&path`. And if you want to search in `$PWD` and subdirectories, execute `:set path+=**` (IIRC)
If `:sp **/beginingoffilename<tab>` clears the command line, that's odd. What's the value of your `&wildmode` option?

Comment: `:tabfind` is even easier that `:tab sfind` ;)

Answer (score 0):

I wound up using a solution inspired by [dash-tom-bang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47785590/430766)'s answer, which is essentially independent of the project and its tree structure.

```
map <C-b> :tabfind 
imap <C-b> <C-o><C-b>
set path=.,,**,/usr/include
```

The drawback is that I shouldn't use `<C-b>` in my home directory or a similarly full directory. But for that I recommend to fallback to:

```
map <C-n> :tabnew 
imap <C-n> <C-o><C-n>
```

Comment: This `path` will only find things in subdirectories of your current working directory which may be something to be aware of. (That's why I like to set the `path` based on a determined "project root," so it doesn't matter what directory Vim is in when I do the `:find`.)

Comment: @dash-tom-bang Yes, but I made the trade-off for the flexibility of not having to actually set up da project-root. Fair point, though.